# ZooKeeper returning junk characters for HBase server address

Tags: scala, hadoop, hbase, playframework-2.0, apache-zookeeper

how's it goin?

Sorry if I sound stupid here.

I'm trying to create a basic play2.0 - HBase app. When I try to connect HBase from play, ZooKeeper is returning me junk characters for HBase server address.

```
def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
 val conf =  HBaseConfiguration create
 val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)

 // list the tables
 val listtables = admin.listTables()
 listtables.foreach(println)
}
```

I've nailed down to the weak spot and it's at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker. It's loading data with junk values for local address and port, which is then passed down to HServerAddress class for further action.

I've looked at my hbase-site.xml (contains just localhost) and hbase-default.xml, which are looking just fine as directed by Apache.

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///Users/gchandra/Applications/hbase-0.92.1/data-store/hbase</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Pasted below is stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: ?���5610@L-C02FF6MTDF91��192.168.1.4,64256,1332739256936
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.<init>(HServerAddress.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
at services.HBaseConnection$.main(HBaseConnection.scala:20)
at services.HBaseConnection.main(HBaseConnection.scala)
```

Appreciate it if someone could help me out here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just searched for your exception message and found this: [Re: IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/24159)

Do you have a version mismatch between your client library and your server?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, still the same. Think I've to try in another Unix box. I'll post any updates.

Answer (score 0):

It worked in another box, Not sure why it was acting weird in my local! Thanks all!